# How can i make a dynamic list in Flutter where user can add items through a textfield and delete the item again?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, textfield

I want to have a textinputfield for the user and when he tips in something and clicks on a button the input should be shown in a list item. The user should also have the option to delete items of the list just like a in and todo app.

Here you can find my code:

[Link to Code](https://github.com/jjklangbehn/AnimatedList/blob/main/AnimatedList.dart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I decided to write this simple program just to freshen up my skills... You can directly copy paste this code and it should work just fine.

I have used the provider package here to make this a bit more professional, as you can't always rely on setState() to update your UI when tasks are added to your list. And also because you will probably be using the provider more often in the future.

I have added comments in the below code to make it easy to understand. However, do not hesitate to clear up any confusions in the comments :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:todo/list_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider( // This initiates the provider.
      create: (context) => TaskProvider(), // Initiating it here makes this provider data available everywhere in the application
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Dynamic List'),
      ),
      body: const HomePageBody(), // I pass a separate widget here just to make the code a bit cleaner
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet( // This calls a bottom Modal Sheet which pops up while pressing the floating action button
            context: context, builder: (context) => const BottomSheet()),// The modal sheet displays the BottomSheet() Widget which I have defined down in this code.
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// This is where the ListView will be shown
class HomePageBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePageBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> listOfTasks = Provider.of<TaskProvider>(context).getTasks; // This is where the list is being accessed from the Provider file.
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listOfTasks.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              listOfTasks[index],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// This is the BottomSheet Widget where I decided to take User Input from
class BottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomSheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomSheet> createState() => _BottomSheetState();
}

class _BottomSheetState extends State<BottomSheet> {
  String task = ''; // This variable holds the tasks user wants to add
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 20,
        left: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 20, // viewInsets.bottom adds padding from the bottom to avoid keyboard overlapping textfield widget
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TextFormField(// You can use TextField Widget as well
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
            ),
            onChanged: (value) { // This saves the value in the TextField for every character the user types
              task = value; // The value in the TextField is referred to by the 'value' variable
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => saveTask(task),
            child: const Text('Save Task'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void saveTask(String task) {
    Provider.of<TaskProvider>(context, listen: false).addTasks(task); //This is where I am calling the function to add a task to the list. 
    // The 'addTasks()' function is defined in the provider file which is just below
  }
}
```

Here's the list_provider.dart file that I import in above code:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class TaskProvider extends ChangeNotifier { // This is the class where your data exists
// and this is the only place where your data should be manipulated! I explain the reason below...
  final List<String> _tasks = [];

  List<String> get getTasks { // We use a getter to retrieve the list
    return _tasks; // We do that in order to avoid modifications to this list from any outside sources.
  }

  void addTasks(task) {
    _tasks.add(task); // This is simply how you add anything to a list
    notifyListeners(); // This is why we use providers. This function notifies all the children widgets
    // of the Widget where we initiated our provider (see the parent of MaterialApp Widget in the above code)
    // This is why changes to data should be made within this class only as it extends ChangeNotifier,
    // which provides us with notifyListeners() method. Which ultimately notifies the widgets that the data has been modified and its time to rebuild the widgets that rely on this data!
  }
}
```

You can copy paste this code, just make sure to add the provider package in your pubspec.yaml file as shown below.

[image: Image showing provider being added to pubspec.yaml file]

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. Only Problem is when I want to wrap the ListViewBuilder inside a Column the Terminal throws multiple erros. How can I put the ListViewBuilder inside Column?

Comment: Add shrinkwrap: true in your ListView. It's just another attribute of a listview like itemCount and itemBuilder. What it does is makes the ListView take a finite size, as minimum as possible and that would eliminate the error.